# Security Manager vs Access Controller

Tags: java, security

I'm trying to block certain actions from players but not from my game infrastructure and for that I'm using a security manager. It looks like this

```
public class GameSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
@Override
public void checkPackageAccess(String pkg) {
 super.checkPackageAccess(pkg);
 if (isPlayer()) {
  if (pkg.startsWith("ca.hilikus.jrobocom")) {
   if (!"ca.hilikus.jrobocom.player".equals(pkg) && !"ca.hilikus.jrobocom.robot.api".equals(pkg)) {
        throw new SecurityException("No access to game packages");
   }}}
}
}
```

The documentation on security managers is very sparse and most of it is from the 90s. The AccessController situation is even worse. However, I did find [this, section 6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/spec/security-spec.doc6.html) where it states

> We encourage the use of AccessController in application code, while customization of a security manager (via subclassing) should be the last resort and should be done with extreme care.

do you agree with the statement? Can someone explain why that is? if that is the case, *how would I accomplish something similar to the sample code I pasted*? I'm trying to block things like reflection, threading and instantiating some objects based on the context (like with `isPlayer()` above). The only thing the Access Control javadoc discusses is privileged operations inside a special block of code, but *it doesn't show how to use the controller to actually block actions*

Answer (score 2):

Quote from section "6.4.9 `SecurityManager` versus `AccessController`" of the book [Inside Java 2 Platform Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201787911):

> Recall from earlier in this chapter the difference, when invoking a security check, between calling `checkPermission` and calling the other `check` methods defined in the `SecurityManager` class. The choice then was contingent on whether you depended on any pre–Java 2 security manager classes. Now you have another choice: calling either the `checkPermission` method defined in `SecurityManager` or the one defined in `AccessController`. These methods differ in **two major ways**.
>
> First, sometimes no installed `SecurityManager` exists, so you cannot invoke `check` or `checkPermission` methods on it. By contrast, the static methods in `AccessController` are always available to be called. Recall the following idiom for calling `SecurityManager`:
>
> ```
> SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
> if (sm != null)
>     sm.checkPermission(permission);
> ```
>
> But you can always call
>
> ```
> AccessController.checkPermission(permission);
> ```
>
> Thus, regardless of whether a systemwide `SecurityManager` has been installed, if you want to ensure that your security check is always invoked, you should call `AccessController`. Note, however, that some existing applications test whether there is an installed instance of `SecurityManager`. Then, based on the result of this test, which signifies one or the other security states, these applications take different actions. For the backward compatibility of these applications, calling `SecurityManager` is more appropriate.
>
> The second difference is that calling `SecurityManager` does not guarantee a particular access control algorithm; someone might have extended it and installed a custom security manager. By contrast, calling `AccessController` guarantees that the full access control algorithm specified earlier is used. Thus, if you do not want to delegate your security check to a custom security manager, you should call `AccessController` directly. Otherwise, call `SecurityManager`.
>
> Also, be warned that because the `SecurityManager` class defines a general interface for security checks, it does not provide the privilege mechanism that `AccessController` has defined. In fact, if you use the privilege mechanism in your code but later call `SecurityManager` to perform a security check, the privilege status might not be taken into account if the security manager you installed is not the one provided by Java 2 and does not consult `AccessController` or its equivalent.
>
> You might wonder why we provide these choices. Isn't one way of doing things good enough? These choices are based on experience. A balanced trade-off between generality and consistency is needed. In the long run, we expect that custom security managers will not often be needed and that, even when they are defined, they will be built on existing functionality in `AccessController`. In particular, they will provide additional functionality rather than promote incompatible behavior. Nevertheless, in a special environment in which a vastly different sort of security policy must be enforced, a customized security manager conceivably might not be able to use the algorithms implemented by `AccessController`.

You can also take a look at [SecurityManager versus AccessController](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-se-platform-security-architecture.html#GUID-B83ECC0C-02AB-497A-B07D-D74AB9572DC7) section in Oracle's Java Platform, Standard Edition **Security Developer’s Guide**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own SecurityManager nor your own AccessController, what you need is a custom [Permission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Permission.html). After you write one you only need to boot up a SecurityManager and do a security check in every method you want to protect! You might need to do a priveleged action to avoid to much check propagation. :)

Comment: the methods i want to protect are not my methods. they are JDK methods, like reflection, or creating a new class loader. How can i use a custom permissions for that??

Comment: I don't know if I get You right, you wrote a java library(game) that will be handed out for people to extend it and play (write players code) or you just have a game and you want to forbid someone tampering with it ?

Comment: The former. So i'm trying to block some other actions that are not implemented by me but by the JDK

Comment: Then there's going to be a problem :( because there are two ways of enabling SecurityManager: either by jvm options or porgramatically from within your code, but only one instance of SecurtyManager can be running so somebody can override your settings. I sugges you lookup other options of protecting like code obfuscation or crypto with online state storage.

Answer (score 1):

(For the benefit of future users)

The answer to this is that you should provide a Security Policy for the application. If that is not possible to control, then you are simply out of luck.

In the policy, you would grant access to some suitable subset for your "hosted extensions", where as your "game packages" would be granted AllPermissions. Then, you create Permissions for your library and grant suitable access to the "hosted extensions".

Then in your APIs, you would do something like;

`public String someMethod( String someArg )
{
    if( System.getSecurityManager() == null )
        return internalSomeMethod( someArg );
    MyPermission required = new MyPermission( "whatever" );
    AccessController.checkPermission( required );
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>()
    {
        public String run()
        {
            return internalSomeMethod( somArg );
        }
    } );
}`

private String someInternalMethod( String someArg ){...}

So, even if the "hosted extensions" ONLY have "MyPermission", the game engine can have AllPermissions and allowed to do anything it wants, whereas the "extension" couldn't even read a System Property.